# Upload image to imgur without exposing client_id, but directly from browser

Tags: image, security, uploading, imgur

OK, I want to start using imgur for my new web app (on all browsers and my server) and will submit anonymous images for paid storage, but from the user's browser to minimize loading on my server. Almost all the software runs in javascript client-side (with very few server interactions... hence fast and distributed).

Currently the only way I can see using the ID from imgur is to first bring the image to my server and then send to imgur with my ID. Because putting it into the javascript on the browser makes the ID visible to the world.

I was hoping for some kind of solution like: I call imgur to get a token good for ONE time use only. The user gets the token from my server (which I would have previously polled imgur to get) and then I send to my javascript code on their browser, which would upload the image directly to imgur with the token. The token is then dead, and it doesn't matter if someone else sees it, it cannot be used again.

Does imgur API have anything like this? Or maybe another solution? Key points are:

1. Don't upload to my server since I wont keep it there anyway
2. Don't expose my client ID to world on user's browser in Javascript

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To further clarify the above question, in particular I am extracting completed canvas for dispatch to imgur. It makes no sense to move the image to my server just so I can send backdoor to imgur. SO (both so and Stack Overflow) my 2 points above are critical to this process. Hope that helps improve it.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand. My intention is to *help* you get an answer. If you ask a broad open-ended question without showing that you have [researched the topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) and without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), people will not have a way to answer your question and still fit the Q & A format. Many who are volunteering their time are offended if you don't provide *broken code* to fix, as that implies you expect *others to write code* for you. Also, your tags don't even indicate what programming language you are using.

Comment: Didn't mean to dis you. Bottomline is after 40 yrs of doing this, of course I researched it. And, the question was more of feature detection than how to. I know how to do this 5 ways from hell. But I want to do it the way they should have designed it. AND, I was hoping that someone at imgur/SO new that they did just that. In the mean time I will expose my client ID, Don't worry, I often read the SO as my first choice to find an answer and often find the "have you tried this or that?" answer to be "why did you bother writing this and making me read it". I will endeavor to continue my SO journey

Comment: I find this a perfectly valid question and the comment of NightOwl abolutely misplaced. Maybe the question looked different at that time... Anyway I'm facing the same problem. Did you further research the topic, Larry?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any method to do it directly from browser yet.
But you can use your backend as proxy to handle the upload. For example in python (Django) you can stream file from client and send it to imgur in chunk and yield it when it done, for example 1MB at a time. This could prevent overload of your backend memory.
I can provide you a codes on how to implement that method. But I'm not going to post the codes now since it not related to your topic.